# Adding data-priority to Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So I am using Kendo UI Grid and I want to add data-priority to the columns that way I can hide and show columns depending on the viewport I know this is possible with JQuery Mobile (http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_tables_columntoggle) .But Is this possible in Kendo UI?

Comment: have a look at this part of the documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.minScreenWidth  I suspect this is possibly what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom attributes to the column headers using the [headersAttributes](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.headerAttributes) configuration.

Use it like this (if you are using pure javascript version of Kendo):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
 columns: [ {
  field: "name",
  title: "Name",
  headerAttributes: {"data-priority": "1"}
  },
  // more columns...
});
```